# zipfileset is not working for batchtest when running the junit from jar and getting classnotfound exception

Tags: ant, junit

I am trying to run the Junit test cases inside one jar(test.jar) in junit task under ant.

I am getting classnotfound exception.

```
<formatter type="xml" />
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.report.dir}">
                <zipfileset src="${rootdir}/test.jar" includes="**/AllGUITestSuite.class" />
            <!--    <fileset dir="${build.test.classes}">
                    <include name="**/AllGUITestSuite.class" />
                </fileset> -->
    </batchtest>
```

I am getting following exception
I am using ant 1.8.2 version. Exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.naveen.guitest.TestSuite
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)

Comment: Ant version? and elaborate the exception string

Comment: I am using ant 1.8.2 version.

Comment: i am also facing the ClassNotFoundException. I am using ant 1.9.4. Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the question is over 4 years old, I don't know whether it is still relevant.

Anyhow, it looks like you need to define the classpath.
If the missing classes are within your jar, try setting the classpath to the test.jar itself, like this:

```
<classpath>
  <fileset dir="${rootdir}" includes="test.jar"/>
</classpath>
```